# What does greater than and ampersand mean in a bash statement?

Tags: bash

For example, if I have a statement:

```
/home/1/test.sh > /home/1/test.log 2>&1
```

What does the last part of this do effectively?

Thanks.

Comment: @Freddy Yes, I didn't realize google had added symbols as meaningful search terms, 
that's my bad. Makes looking these things up a lot easier. Someone can close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Greater than or 1 greater than means redirect stdout (standard output, what's usually written to the terminal. 2 greater than means redirect stderr (standard error).

In 2>&1, you are redirecting stderr AND (ampersand) stdout.

Comment: In this case, where are you redirecting it to? Thanks!

Comment: In the example you gave, you'd be redirecting it to the filename following >, so /home/1/test.log. Note that there is a more readable but less portable version of the above: /home/1/test.sh &> /home/1/test.log.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I understand. So it's redirecting stdout to the file, then redirecting stderr to stdout, which is being redirected to the file, so both stdout and stderr are redirected to the log file. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: `2>&1` as such doesn't redirect stderr and stdout, though (that's what `&>` does). It redirects stderr to wherever stdout is pointing at that moment.